# Suggestions on how to check an array against a database table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Here's what I have:

1. 1 **database table** containing approx 2000 records, indexed. (The important column is a string of 25 characters).
2. An **array** containing approx 30 strings of 25 characters.

What I'd like to do:

1. I need to check the **array** against the **database table** to find any string
   matches.
2. I need to be able to identify what values in the array only match any in the table, if any

I don't really want to have to run each string in the array against the table in a separate query fashion using a loop, I'm thinking there must be a more efficient way to do this.

Any ideas would be appreciated. I'm using PHP 5.4.3 and MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Just use an IN clause:-

```
SELECT somecolumn
FROM someTable
WHERE someCoumn IN ('a string', 'another string', 'etc')
```

Doing it in php maybe (assuming the array is already escaped to be SQL safe):-

```
$sql = "SELECT somecolumn
FROM someTable
WHERE someCoumn IN ('".implode("','", $someArray)."')";
```

If you want a count of how many matches there are on each item (including those with 0) then something like this might be better:-

```
<?php

$result = $db->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE CheckValues
(CheckValue varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`CheckValue`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;");

$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO CheckValues (CheckValue) VALUES('".implode("','", $someArray)."')");

$result = $db->query("SELECT CheckValue, COUNT(b.someCoumn) AS someCount
FROM CheckValues a
LEFT OUTER JOIN someTable b ON a.CheckValue = b.someCoumn
GROUP BY CheckValue");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    echo "$row[CheckValue] - $row[someCount] <br />";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks very much everyone, I had in the back of my head that the .implode function would come in useful here. I run my array against the table using IN and .implode, I write the results to an array and compare to give an outcome. Perfect. Thanks again

Comment: Edited to suggest a solution if you want counts (not something that is obvious in your question)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by other people, you can use `IN` clause. Here's a sample that uses `MySQLi` instead of `mysql_*` so you don't have to worry about escaping and injection.

```
$criteria=array(/* string-to-search */);
$sql="SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` IN (".implode(",",array_fill(0,count($criteria),"?")).")";
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

call_user_func_array(array($stmt,"bind_param"),array_merge(array(str_repeat("s",count($criteria))),$criteria));

$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: While a clever way of binding the parameters for an IN clause from an array, I wish that mysqli had a native way of doing this that was more readable!

Answer (score 1):

You should use MYSQL WHERE IN clause.

Use like below:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('.implode(', ', $array).')'
```